# How to check null value or zero

Tags: vb.net

Using VB.Net

I want to check whether the table row is null or 0

Code

```
 sCmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT * from table1)", conObjects.myConnection)
        dReader = sCmd.ExecuteReader
        While dReader.Read()
 If dReader.Item(11) <> "0" And dReader.Item(11) IsNot Nothing Then
msgbox ("Not NUll or 0")
End if
End while
```

Showing Error as "`Operator '<>' is not defined for type 'DBNull' and string "0"`"

Why i am getting this error, How to solve this problem.

Need VB.Net Code Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always use `AndAlso` and `OrElse` instead of `And` and `Or`. 
With `AndAlso` the latter expression is only evaluted if the former returned `true`. On this way you can avoid exceptions and make your code more efficient.

But apart from that, you should use [`reader.IsDBNull(index)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull.aspx):

```
If Not dReader.IsDBNull(11) AndAlso dReader.GetString(11) <> "0" Then

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using **[`AndAlso`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**

```
If (dReader.Item(11) IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (cint(dReader.Item(11)) <> 0) Then
    msgbox ("Not NUll or 0")
End if
```

basically what it does is, when the first expression is already `true`, the second expression is not evaluated.

Comment: Why `OrElse` instead of `AndAlso`?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here: one is that you use `And` instead of `AndAlso`: the former will cause your whole line to be evaluated, where the latter will only evaluate the second argument if its first argument is already `True`.

Your second problem is that you check for "not zero" before you check for "Nothing", and so your first part can fail before the second part is evaluated.

Try this instead:

```
If dReader.Item(11) IsNot Nothing AndAlso dReader.Item(11) <> "0" Then
```

Also, it's been a while since I did ADO, but shouldn't you be checking `IsDbNull` instead of comparing to `Nothing`?  Perhaps VB takes care of that for you, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

```
If Convert.ToString(dReader.Item(11)) <> "0" AndAlso dReader.IsDBNull(11)=False
```